# Terminal messed up after running ncurses program

Tags: c++, linux, terminal, ncurses

This is my program (well, `main` calls this method for an instance of NCursesViewController):

```
void NCursesViewController::Run(){
    initscr(); //Init ncurses standard screen
    raw();
    printw("WELCOME");
    endwin(); //Free Ncurses resources
    getch();
}
```

After I run this on an Ubuntu terminal, the terminal remains in some strange state; whatever I type, the cursor does not move. If I press Enter , it does run whatever I typed. So I cannot see what I type... is there any workaround? It's bothersome having to open a terminal every time. I saw in a similar question that they saved and restored the terminal settings, but they used ssh and tty.

Comment: call `noraw();` to restore cooked mode afaik.

Comment: As a workaround you could try saving the original `termios()` state, and restore it before exiting.

Comment: @Nidhoegger, that did it: post that comment as an answer

Comment: @RyanHaining: That also worked, but I think calling `noraw()` is cleaner

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should call `endwin()` just before exiting, instead of before the `getch()`.

When you call `getch()`, `ncurses` mode is reentered and another call to `endwin()` is necessary. (See `man initscr`: "Calling `refresh` or `doupdate` after a temporary escape causes the program to resume visual mode." `getch()` automatically calls `wrefresh` unless no change has been made to the window; since you haven't turned echoing off, the window is modified by the echo.)

I usually do the `endwin` call in an `atexit()` handler, which makes it more likely that the `endwin()` will execute. To be safer,  you should also make sure that the process is not killed by an uncaught signal such as `SIGINT` or `SIGSEGV`, although obviously you can't do anything about `SIGKILL`.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> endwin(); //Free Ncurses resources
> getch();
> ```

Try removing any / all "curses calls" after endwin().

In this case, comment out the getch(); and try it.
You might review your code to find any additional curses function that occur after endwin().

After my endwin() call, I have some non-curses log outputs, and a couple of cout's, but no curses ... it is about 20 lines from end of main.

Comment: Upon endwin(), my screen restores to its condition prior to the initscr().  Perhaps you want to simply swap these two lines to pause for the user.  Then, pressing a key will cause endwin() and the restore.